# Deleting a discord message from discordgo

Tags: go, discord, discordgo

I am trying to delete a discord message using [discordgo](https://github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo). Currently I have the [ping pong example](https://github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo/tree/master/examples/pingpong), however instead of writing a message I want to delete the message.

I have currently got this far:

```golang
func messageCreate(s *discordgo.Session, m *discordgo.MessageCreate) {

    if m.Author.ID == s.State.User.ID || m.Author.Bot {
        return
    }

    if m.Content == "ping" {
        s.ChannelMessageDelete(m.ChannelID, m.ID)
    }
}
```

But the implementation does not delete the message even though other code in the block will run. I am a bit of a newb to go and I don't know if there is some future error .. or something like the bot does not have the correct discord permissions?

Comment: Ensure your bot has delete permissions. `ChannelMessageDelete` will return an error that you can inspect as well.

Comment: @Jesse Yes that works, they need to have `Manage Messages` checkbox for creating the oauth url, put this as answer and I will accept

Comment: You can actually post an answer to your own question -- I don't want to take credit for a solution that you found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not posting was because the bot did not have the `Manage Messages` permission. This can be done by checking the `Manage Messages` checkbox when generating the invite link on the OAuth tab.